# Looking for solution without exception

Tags: android, exception, textview, imageview

I have a little passage in my code I do not like.

```
imageView=null;
textView=null;
try{
  imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
}catch (Exception e){
  textView = (TextView) convertView;
}
```

I have to dynamically decide if convertView is an ImageView or an TextView. My code is working fine, but as said before, I don't like him. Is there another why to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

without seeing the rest of your code, the only answer that comes to my mind is to check with instance of

```
if (convertView instanceof ImageView) {

} else {

}
```